# trying to do a simple hover in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
OnMouseOver="$('.class') .hover
    (function(){ 
 $(this).addClass('.hoverclass'); 
 }, function() {
   $(this).removeClass('.hoverclass');
  });"
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to do the hover thing on all elements that have the class "class", then:

```
$('.class').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hoverclass");
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/icixu4)

Changes from yours:

- It's not a string. I'm not sure where your quote came from, but I'm thinking it was an HTML attribute. You would just put this somewhere during page load, like within a [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.
- You don't include the leading dot when you're calling `addClass` / `removeClass` / `toggleClass`. The dot isn't part of the class name.
- May as well use `toggleClass`, since that's what it's for.

Possibly worth mentioning that you don't need jQuery or JavaScript for this unless you need to support IE6. CSS already has this, the `:hover` pseudo-class. So you can put your styles there rather than in a separate `hoverClass`, e.g.:

```
.class:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
```

...would turn an element with class "class" blue with an underline when the mouse was over it.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/icixu4/2)

In IE6 this only works on `a` elements; in IE7 upward and nearly all other browsers, it 
works on all elements.

---

**Edit**: In your note below, you say you only want to do this to one element (at least, I think that's what you're saying). You can do that by uniquely-identifying the element — either by where it is, or by using an `id` attribute. So for instance, to only do this for the element with the `id` "foo":

```
$('#foo').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hoverclass");
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/icixu4/3)

(And that holds for the CSS solution as well:

```
#foo:hover {
    /* ...style rules here... */
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/icixu4/4)

Comment: @veidt: Just one element? Or one element *at a time*? Either way, the updated answer should help (the original answer did one element at a time; the update lets you do one element, period).

Comment: I changed it to OnMouseOver= $('.item').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});

And it's still not working, all i want is to have a background hover on the item class using the hover class. :/

Comment: @veidt: See the examples, you don't want OnMouseOver at all.

Comment: @veidt: In case you haven't used JSBin before: As you move your mouse over any of those examples, you should see an "Edit in jsbin" button appear in the upper right-hand corner. Just click that to see the source of the samples (the "JavaScript" bit on the left can be thought of as a linked .js file). You can also enter "edit" mode simply by adding `/edit` to the end of any of the URLs, so for instance, to edit http://jsbin.com/icixu4, use http://jsbin.com/icixu4/edit.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add jQuery commands to an `onMouseOver` event as a string. You, rather, execute jQuery, after DOM finishes rendering, and jQuery attaches and handles all the functions and events so you don't have to.

```
jQuery(document).ready(
  function() {
    // this function will be executed when DOM is ready

    // ...and this will attach your hover functions to
    // all the elements that have class 'class'
    jQuery('.class').hover(
      function(){ 
        jQuery(this).addClass('hoverclass'); 
      }, 
      function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('hoverclass');
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the right hand side of the expression. By having the quotes around, you are creating a String and not evaluating the expression. Also may I ask why you are storing the jQuery result object?

Answer (score 0):

As T.J. Crowder points out, you really don't need to use Javascript to achieve this. All you need to do is use the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class, like this:

```
.some_element {
  color: #eee;
}
.some_element:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Much cleaner, much simpler. Works in pretty much every modern browser, including IE7+.

Comment: As I've already pointed that out, I'm not seeing why post it a second time?

Comment: Because there's no need for a Javascript solution—CSS can handle this perfectly adequately. Hence, the less verbose answer.